# Search and Replace SSN between tags

Tags: regex, search, replace, notepad++

I want to search SSN and remove the dashes. But I need to make sure the SSN is in between

```
<Employee_ID>111-22-3333</Employee_ID>
```

only and not other places in the file. Can someone help so I end up with

```
<Employee_ID>111223333</Employee_ID>
```

Answer (score 3):

Search for

```
(?<=<Employee_ID>)(\d{3})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{4})(?=</Employee_ID>)
```

with Regular Expression as Search Mode and replace with

```
$1$2$3
```

`(?<=<Employee_ID>)` is a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), ensuring "`<Employee_ID>`" is before the SSN but not matched.

`(?=</Employee_ID>)` is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), ensuring "`</Employee_ID>`" is following the SSN but not matched.

`$x` is the content of the other three [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in brackets.

Comment: Checked and works in Notepad++ - never got into lookbehind and lookaheads with regex ... really useful

Comment: Why optional dashes `-?` and not just dashes `-`?

Comment: @Bentoy13, I am not used to the SSN, thought there could maybe be sometimes only 1 dash, if two dashes are fix, the question marks can of course be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Find What:** `(\d{3})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})`
**Replace with:** `\1\2\3`

**Explanation:**

1st Capturing group `(\d{3})`
        `\d` match a digit `[0-9]`
        Quantifier: `{3}` Exactly 3 times - so this matches 3 digits

2nd Capturing group `(\d{2})` Matches 2 digits
3rd Capturing group `(\d{4})` Matches 4 digits

Comment: Checked and worked in Notepad++ - did not know you could use \1\2\3 - I learnt something

Comment: The OP says explicitly: "in between `<Employee_ID>...</Employee_ID>`
**only** and not other places in the file". Your solution replaces all SSN, there is no check on the enclosing tag.

Comment: @Bentoy Please see post edit history. At the time I wrote the answer, the tags didn't exist in the question.